# i am getting error Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

i am using react and when i tried to use map function in it ,i had multiple components inside map return function.so inorder to contain i used dummy parent element and started showing the error ** Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop** .i don't know how to include key in the dummy parent <>.will you help me out.

```
                           {
                             dataArray.map((item,key)=>{
                                return(
                                     <>

                                    <td key={key}>{item.country}</td>
                                     <td key={key}>{item.city}</td>
                                    </> 
                                )})
                            }
```

By adding the dummy parent i am getting that error unique key.is there any way i can **remove the unique key error keeping both td in the return statement**

Comment: intresting question.just try to use one parent

Answer (score 6):

Add a key to the *fragment*, not to the individual `<td>`s:

```
{
  dataArray.map((item, key) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment key={key}>
        <td>{item.country}</td>
        <td>{item.city}</td>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  })
}
```

Comment: To add to this, from the docs: "You can use <></> the same way you’d use any other element except that it doesn’t support keys or attributes."

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

So you must define it as a React.Fragment, and cannot use the `<></>` syntax to add the key

Comment: what if there is select outside and having multiple options inside with submenu. then using React.Farment gives error.